# Unable to plot Integral

Tags: plotting

I am following an example taken directly from the Mathematica book V5.2 by Stephen Wolfram, here is a screenshot from the book.
[image: 1]

And here is my implementation, the integral fails to plot. This looks something that is fairly straightforward and simple, I believe there has been no major change as to `Plot` function from V5 to V12. It should still work, isn't it?

[image: 3]

Code:

```
Integrate[(1/(x^3 - 1)), x]
Plot[%, {x, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Please include code. Screenshots are not that helpful

Comment: @user6014 added code to the post

Comment: try `Integrate[(1/(x^3 - 1)), x]; Plot[Re@%, {x, 1, 2}]`?

Comment: @kglr Tried out your suggestion, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @kglr what version are you running?

Comment: Rene, it works both in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10) and version 12.0 (Wolfram Cloud)

Comment: Notice in the screenshot from the book there is `Log[ x - 1 ]` but in the MMA version 12 screenshot there is `Log[ 1 - x ]`.

Comment: @LouisB You are right, the integral results are different between the book and MMA.

Comment: Look at `FunctionDomain[f[x], x]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old *The Mathematica Book* you are using is showing an incorrect result for the integral, an old Mathematica bug that was later corrected. The integration result shown does not have real values in the domain `{1, 2}`. The real part of the integral gives a plot very much like the on the book shows.

In recent versions of Mathematica the example has been changed to

```
Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x]
```

See the 1st example under Integrate > Examples > Basic Examples. This can be plotted with

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

which gives

[image: plot]

The integral in the old book does have reals values for negative values of `x`; it takes the form of the current example reflected about the y-axis.

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Integrate[1/(x^3 - 1), x], {x, -10, -1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I am trying to find the errata for The Mathematica Book and so far have been unsuccessful. I am not even sure if there is one. Your advise?

Comment: @ReneDuchamp. I am not aware of Wolfram ever publishing errata for its documentation. It does make corrections as each new version is released. Also, the example you show would have worked for you if you were running V5. The problem is not the documentation, but that `Integrate` returned a bad result in V5.